# NetworkXError: Input is not a correct Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a network map in Python using NetworkX with labels to find protential connections between people. Currently I have a 1,316 x 1,316 matrix of 1's and 0's that represent if there is a connection or not. I have been able to import this data into pyhon using a dataframe. [Screenshot of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEDoU.png)  This is a small screenshot of the python dataframe. You can see the column and row names are numbers but at the end of the list they turn into actual names. If I remove the names and make a grid of just 1's and 0's NetworkX will allow me to turn this into a connection graph but it is almost useless without the labels to know who is connected to who. When including the labels in dataframe and trying to run the code listed below I recieve an error.

**Error**

> NetworkXError: Input is not a correct Pandas DataFrame.

**Code**

```
Network = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('H:\\Network.csv')

G1 = nx.to_networkx_graph(Network)
```

I will admit to being quite new at this so any and all help will be appreciated. If you have any advice on why I'm getting this error or a better way to go about this, I am open to suggestions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What helped me to solve is to just transform the dataframe to a numpy array. (This only works if shape[0] == shape[1])

here is what I did:

```
Network = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('H:\\Network.csv')

G1 = nx.to_networkx_graph(Network.to_numpy())
```

This should work for you.